# My IP changes every 10 seconds while connected to internet

Tags: ip, port-forwarding, mac-address

I am not a network engineer, I just wanted to check if port 16000 is open for me. I went to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and it showed my IP as 103.5.xx.xxx. However after 15-20 seconds, I refreshed the page, and my IP got changed to 36.255.xx.xxx.

Seems like 36.255.xx.xxx stays as my IP for around 10 seconds and 103.5.xx.xxx stays as my IP for 30 odd seconds. And this is a continuous endless process.

**End goal is to forward port 16000 on my system**. My ISP is Broadway Communication in Bangalore, India. They use MAC addressing. Also I am using TP-Link_D72E router.

**Edit:**

WAN address details:

MAC Address:    28-F1-0E-xx-xx-xx
IP Address: 172.16.xx.xx    PPPoE(Connect Automatically)
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.255
Default Gateway:    103.5.xx.xx
DNS Server: 8.8.8.8 , 0.0.0.0

Comment: I want to play some online game. which requires port 16000 to be forwarded

Comment: What "WAN address" is shown on the router's own status page? And does it match any of the addresses you're seeing in online test pages?

Comment: @grawity, edited the question to include WAN details

Comment: It appears that your ISP has provisioned you on a [private subnet](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) and I presume then uses [NAT](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663) to allow your private IP to access the internet. I don't think there's much you can do except make a request to have your ISP provision you with a static public IP.